# How to delete data using Eloquent query?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I can not delete a row using a simple eloquent query. Even when I am using eloquent can not get the data from DB. I am getting null. But, in DB query method at least I am getting data but can not delete then. Following is my code:

```php
DB::transaction(function () use ($lead, $comment, $request) {
    $lead->save();
    $lead->comments()->save($comment);

    if ($request->deleteAppointment) {
        $calendarEvent = DB::table('calendar_events')->where('id', $request->appointmentId)->first(); // I am getting data here.
        $calendarEvent = CalendarEvent::find($request->appointmentId); // But, here I am getting null, don't know why!
        
        if ($calendarEvent != null) {
            $calendarEvent->delete();
        }
    }
```

**My goal is to get the data using Eloquent and then Delete from database.**

update:
My Database Table
[image]

CalendarEvent.php model

```
class CalendarEvent extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'event_begin' => 'datetime',
        'event_end'   => 'datetime',
        'options'     => 'array',
    ];

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $guarded = [
        'id',
    ];

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany(User::class, 'eventable');
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function attendees()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany(User::class, 'eventable')->withPivotValue('role', 'atendee');
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function companies()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany(Company::class, 'eventable')->withPivotValue('role', 'company');
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function invitees()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany(User::class, 'eventable')->withPivotValue('role', 'invitee');
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function leads()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany(Lead::class, 'eventable')->withPivotValue('role', 'lead');
    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to be using soft deletes. It's possible your model is softdeleted but this won't be reflected when getting it via `DB` because the softdeleted trait is on the model. Check if `deleted_at` is not null

Comment: I don't like to retrieve the data using DB. I want to get it by eloquent and then need to delete. But, at eloquent I am getting null so that I can not delete.

Comment: Your model is probably already soft deleted

Comment: Please provide your CalendarEvent.php file and can you confirm that the record doesn't have a deleted_at timestamp

Comment: @SimonR Hello, I have added CalendarEvent.php. Plz check. Yes there is soft deleted.

Comment: Although it should work out the table name by itself, declare it in your model protected $table = 'calendar_events'; and try again - see if that gets the record

Comment: If you are saying that deleted_at is not null then that is why you're unable to retrieve that record.

Comment: @SimonR Now, I got the point. I actually did not know about the soft delete! Now, I understand what is the problem. It has already been deleted! My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just:

```
CalendarEvent::where('id', $request->appointmentId)->delete();
```

Also, check the deleted_at column.  If that is not null, then the select will return null, unless you add the ->withTrashed() method.

When using Eloquent objects, the SoftDelete trait is used, when using DB:: directly, then the SoftDelete trait is not used.

Comment: Yes, it had been already deleted. My bad. I did not know about the Soft Delete in Laravel.